# Axios create shorter duration for ETIMEDOUT

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a server application (we'll call **ServerApp1**) which is going to be running on an Azure VM instance. I have a separate server (which we'll call **ServerApp2**) on a different machine which will be communicating with ServerApp1 and a separate client. The Azure VM is going to be spun up and/or down depending on need, so it's quite possible that the VM (and thus ServerApp1) aren't even alive to respond to request from ServerApp2. My client is polling ServerApp2 to ask for the status of ServerApp1, but if the VM is currently down then that request hangs for like 20 seconds before issuing an error with code **ETIMEDOUT**. What I'd like is for ServerApp2 to make the request to ServerApp1 to see if it's alive, but after about 1 or 2 seconds of not getting a response to then simply stop and tell the client that's it's not currently running. I thought I could get away with adding a *{timeout:2000}* parameter to my axios call, but this doesn't seem to change the behavior in any noticeable way.
Here's the function that gets called when the client asks ServerApp2 what the status is of ServerApp1:

```
router.get('/getCurrentConsoleStatus', function(req, res) {
    async function getStatus() {
        try {
            const result = await consoleDataService.getConsoleStatus();

            if (result.message === 'Begin listen for job.') {
                console.log('The app is ready!');
            } else {
                console.log('The console app is not ready');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Error communicating with console app: ${error}`);
        }
    }
    getStatus();
});
```

I have a function which creates the root Axios object:

```
var axios = require('axios');

module.exports = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'baseURL',
    timeout: 1000,
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
});
```

And then the function that gets called in **consoleDataService.getConsoleStatus()** looks like this:

```
exports.getConsoleStatus = async function() {
    const res = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: '/status'
    });
    return res.data;
};
```

Comment: Were you trying to add the timeout at the root of the object passed to `axios({ ..., timeout: 2000 })`? That should work. The timeout you pass is only for the request itself and wouldn't account for any boot time (if this is running as a cloud function where the VM takes a bit to start). Try logging out a timestamp inside your function body before you call axios, and then after the await (before the return), just to rule out something else.

Comment: I put a log-timestamp function right before I make the axios call and then another one in the catch statement as that's where the ETIMEDOUT message is being sent when it fails. I get  `[2020-08-04T13:35:21.060Z] Timestamp before making Axios call` and `[2020-08-04T13:35:42.074Z] Timestamp after making Axios call`... so roughly 21 seconds.

Comment: @JonEdwards See updated axios create method in original post. Even though I've set the timeout to be 1000ms, the overall axios call to the ServerApp1 (when the VM is not running) will still timeout around 21 seconds.

Comment: In cases like this, I'll often use `Promise.race` as a failover time out. You could set it up something like this:
    const getConsoleStatus = () => Promise.race([
        new Promise(async (fulfilled, rejected) => {
           const response = await axios({
          method: 'get',
            url: '/status'
          });
            fulfilled(response.data);
          }),
          new Promise((fulfilled, rejected) => {
           setTimeout(() => rejected(), 1000);
          }),
        ]);
    };
I'm pretty sure I've got a syntax error in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JonEdwards for the suggestion to use [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race). I ended up solving the issue with this function which tries to take the first promise which resolves first.

```
exports.getConsoleStatus = () => {
    var sleep = function() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(function() {
                resolve({ status: false });
            }, 2000);
        });
    };

    var fetch = async function() {
        const res = await http({
            method: 'get',
            url: '/status'
        });
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve(res.data);
        });
    };

    async function getStatus() {
        const asyncFunctions = [sleep(), fetch()];
        const result = await Promise.race(asyncFunctions);
        return result;
    }

    return getStatus();
};
```